# Indy certificate authentication

Tags: http, delphi, ssl, indy

I need to connect to a web service with Delphi and Indy v10 using a certificate authentification.

I have following this tutorial:

[IndySSL - using certificate authentication - Client side issues [zz]](http://blog.csdn.net/happy4nothing/article/details/201265)

but I obtain a `400 Bad Request` response.

This is my code. It seems that the certificat is ignored. If I comment these lines I obtain the same `400`.

```
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.CertFile:= 'certificate_file.crt';
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.KeyFile:=  'private_key.pem';
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.RootCertFile:= 'myissuercerts.cer';
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Links  : 1) [Indy-SSL-Examples](https://github.com/rlove/Indy-SSL-Examples/blob/master/pascal/echodemo/TestForm.pas) 2) [IdTCPServerwithSSL](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=872800)

Comment: Do the IOHandler's `OnStatus/Ex` or `OnVerifyPeer` events give you any useful details? Assuming you are using HTTPS, the fact that you are getting an HTTP response at all means that SSL/TLS is successfully encrypting the connection, since encryption is negotiated before an HTTP request/response can then be exchanged. Normally a faulty certificate would cause the SSL/TLS handshake to fail immediately, before HTTP is exchanged. But it is possible that the web server could take note of any certificate issues, allow the encryption to succeed, and then return an HTTP failure response.

Comment: But if that is not the case, then you should be looking at the content of your actual HTTP request rather than focusing on your certificate.  Why do you suspect the certificate is at fault? Have you talked to the web server admin?

Comment: @Remy : I got IOHandler details, all seems good, I got "SSL negotiation finished successfully" but finally "Disconnected" with Delphi error "http1.1 400 Bad Request". I do the same with PHP and its working well, but I need to connect using Delphi.

Comment: @Remy : I got log with IdLogFile too and I have the message "400 No required SSL certificate was sent", seems the SSLOptions are ignored, note : the certificats are the good one as it works in PHP CLI.